# Are the order of routes in a Rails app significant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So, I work with a bit of a behemoth. A 15-year-old rails app which has a few... hundred... controllers, all with their own routes.

Perhaps unsurprisingly, the page loads aren't the snappiest (although not so slow it poses a problem), and this got me thinking.

Is the order in which the routes are defined significant?
Will routes defined later on in the list take longer to match, or are they indexed to speed up the searching process?

Answer (score 4):

[RailsGuides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/routing.html) mentions this

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action’s
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first.

Having a lot of RESTful routes actually can affect the speed of the process , [Documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/routing.html) actually hints at this

> If your application has many RESTful routes, using :only and :except to generate only the routes that you actually need can cut down on memory use and speed up the routing process.

Answer (score 1):

Current Router in rails creates a graph to optimize routes lookup.

Order matters because two routes that matches the same url will trigger the first one defined, but the router does not try each route on a sequential order.

This RailsConf talk explains how the Router works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEC-QoZeBkM

If you find your page not responding fast enough I really doubt the router is the problem, you should profile the request (use something like mini-profiler).